# Loading json file on IBM Watson Studios

Tags: python, json, pandas

I am new to python and teaching myself to code.

I am trying to load a json file on IBM Watson Studio notebook however I am getting a `ValueError`.

This is the line of code I am using but I'm getting the following `ValueError`:

`df = pd.read_json(body, orient='values')`

I would like to seek your advice and guidance on this.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the entire traceback and the json you're trying to load ?

Comment: in addition to what @SitiSchu has said, also format the code segments for clarity.

Comment: Hey buddy, welcome to SO, have a read of [ask] and please post a sample of your dataset so we can replicate the error/debug.The sample has to be in textual format so we can copy it into our IDE's/Notebooks.